# properties of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix can we conclude $A^{n}$ is positive define too? Why?

For example for $n=2$: $x^{T}(AA)x=x^{T}(AA^{T})x=(x^{T}A)^2>0$;
for $n>2$?

Comment: why will $AA$ equal $AA^T$?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha, $A=A^T$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: A matrix is positive definite if and only if its eigenvalues are $>0$.

Add that the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are …

Comment: I know it, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean that my proof is false?

Comment: $A$ is positive definite implies all its eigenvalues are positive. Eigenvalues of $A^n$ are the $n^{th}$ powers of the eigenvalues of $A$, which will be positive too. Hence $A^n$ has to be positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

We have proof that for all colum vectors $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
v^TA^nv\geq 0
$$
If $n=2m$ is even set $B=A^{m}$,
\begin{align}
v^TA^nv 
=
&
v^TBBv
\\
=
&
v^T\Big(B^T\Big)^TBv
\\
=
&
\Big(B^Tv\Big)^TBv
\\
=
&
\Big(Bv\Big)^TBv\geq 0
\\
\end{align}
If $n=2m+1$ is odd set $B=A^{m}$,
\begin{align}
v^TA^nv 
=
&
v^TBABv
\\
=
&
v^T\Big(B^T\Big)^TABv
\\
=
&
\Big(B^Tv\Big)^TA\big(Bv\big)
\\
=
&
\Big(Bv\Big)^TA\big(Bv\big)\geq 0
\\
\end{align}
Note that $B$ is no sigular and the oparator $\mathbb{R}^n\ni v\mapsto Bv\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is injetive.

**Remark** Remember that, If $A^T=A$, $B_1=A$, $B_2=AA$,..., $B_{n+1}=B_nA$ then $B_1^T=A^T=A=B_1$, $B_2^T=(AA)^T=A^TA^T=AA=B_2$,..., $B_{n+1}^T=(B_nA)^T=A^TB_n^T=AB_n=B_{n+1}$.

Comment: thanks, but in the end of proof I think you lost one transpose, yes?

Comment: @user115927, I use in my answer the fact that $Av=\lambda\cdot v\Leftrightarrow v^T(Av)=v^T(\lambda\cdot v)=\lambda\|v\|^2$. Then, $\lambda\geq 0\Leftrightarrow v^T(Av)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is positive definite when all of its eigenvalues are positive. If we assume that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive then can we show that all of the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are positive?

Assume that $A$ is positive definite. Let $\lambda > 0$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $\det(I-\lambda A)=0$. Now, consider:
$$\det(I-\lambda^2A^2) = \det((I-\lambda A)(I+\lambda A)) = \det(I-\lambda A)\cdot \det(I + \lambda A) = 0.$$
It follows that $\lambda^2 > 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Similarly, since
$$I-\lambda^nA^n = (I-\lambda A)(I+\lambda A+\lambda^2A^2 + \cdots + \lambda^{n-1}A^{n-1})$$
we see that $\lambda^n>0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. We can conclude that $A^n$ is positive definite.

Comment: thanks a lot.I think, one of the properties of positive definite matrix is its eigenvalues are positive, But you say it is it's definition, yes? I read if $X^{T}AX>0$ for every $X$ we say this matrix is positive definite

Comment: @user115927 You're welcome. Don't forget to click the up arrow if you found the answer useful and to tick the tick for your favourite answer. There are several equivalent definitions for positive definite matrices. See here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations